# How to send JSONArray through a Rest API

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, api

I need some help with REST APIs. I'm trying to send JSON data through an API by using Postman's Body to test it. It appears to work, but when I check the Array by Debugging the code it says that the Array's size is 0.

I'm trying to send this:

```
{
   "data":[
      { 
         "name":"",
         "valor":"",
         "check":"0",
         "ind":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"",
         "valor":"* FT NPR **",
         "check":"1",
         "ind":"0"
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm using Java EE. I've tried to parsing the code to String but I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or if it just doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
@GET
@Path("subGroup")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response definedSubGrupo(@QueryParam("Us") int US, JSONArray data) 
{
   String Data=UtilClass.definedSubGrupo(data);
   return UtilClass.getReturn(Data);
}
```

I expected the full JSON that I sent, but the actual output is nothing (size=0).

Thank you.

Comment: This request here is not a JSONArray - it's a JSONObject that has JSONArray inside it, accessible by "data" property.

Comment: Updated with an example of how to retrieve the JSONArray. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on a JavaEE container, and, given the annotations you're specifying, you're building on top of JAX-RS.
With JAX-RS you can accept a request body as a plain `String`

```
public Response definedSubGrupo(@QueryParam("Us")final int US, final String jsonBody) { ... }
```

You can then convert that `jsonBody` `String` to an object representing the JSON document structure using one of the available libraries in the market (JSON-java, Gson, Jackson, etc.).

For example, with Jackson, you'd have

```
final TreeNode treeNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonBody);
```

With JSON-Java, you can have

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonBody);
final JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
```

---

As of now, what you're telling JAX-RS is basically "*map the request body to this `JSONArray` class*".
Unfortunately the class layout of `JSONArray` seems not compatible with the JSON you're sending, so JAX-RS simply create a new, "empty", instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the List of your Object like this:

```
public Response definedSubGrupo(@QueryParam("Us") int US, List<YourObject> data)
```